# Trying to write websocket program in Java

Tags: websocket, jmeter

I am trying to write a program which suppose to send requests to a server using websocket technology, I am using jmeter in order to do that and I am using WebSocket sampler. I am trying to send audio file using this technology anyone can help how to maintain this kind of test using this sampler?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is. Do want (a) to write a program to send these websocket requests, or do you want (b) to perform a load test with JMeter?

If (a) you might want to take a look here: https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/74e30c17bdf4cb90a9a22e3eca7ef581106a01a7/src/main/java/eu/luminis/websocket/?at=master 
You could use the WebSocketClient class to setup a websocket connection and use its sendBinaryFrame method to send an audio file.

If (b) install the plugin https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers, see the readme for how to use it.